# How to restore permission for editing wiki on TFS online?

Tags: tfs, permissions, azure-devops, azure-web-roles, tfvc

I am an admin on a TFS online project, and I have created a wiki and written some pages in it. However, today I cannot access it to edit these pages nor add sub-pages.

The Security button in Wiki page also has been disappeared. How can I restore permission for my account? So I can edit Wiki pages again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask another admin to set the Wiki security `Contribute` permission to `Allow` for your account.

If no other admins in your organization, then you can follow below steps to do that:

1. Add a team member to `Project Collection Administrators` group. 
   (Navigate to  `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_settings/security?_a=members`)
2. Login with this account to manage the wiki security permissions for
   your account.
3. After that you can remove the team member from `Project Collection Administrators` group.

[image]

Comment: The problem I have found, is that my account is a member of an Active Directory group, in which all permissions in wiki security are denied for it.
I have removed myself from it. However, it keeps inheriting permissions from this group to my account.

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib Just try cleaning the browser caches then try it again. If that still not work, then you can try adding your account separately like my account (`AndyLi`) in screenshot, then set the permission explicitly.